# Need to access a component of same id used in two tab panel in a same window , can't use getCmp()

Tags: extjs

I'm working with Extjs 4.0.7, and I am using a panel, and inside that panel I'm using two tabs, each tab contains a form for inserting data.

For each form I added a `dockedItem` component with same `id`. From here my problems started, that component was added to display error message from server or validation error of form.

If we are using that form only one time in a window there is no problem, I used `Ext.getCmp('component-id')`; to `setError` to that component.

But while using two or more forms in an active window, displays `form1`'s error in some times in `form2` error `fieldl`, because every form uses the same component `id`.

I read that you should try to avoid the usage of `getCmp()` in extjs.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use an itemId. The itemId only needs to be unique inside it's container hierarchy:

```
Ext.require('*');

Ext.onReady(function() {

    new Ext.form.Panel({
        renderTo: document.body,
        width: 300,
        items: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Field 1',
            itemId: 'field1'
        },
        tbar: [{
            text: 'Mark',
            handler: function(){
                this.up('form').down('#field1').markInvalid('Foo');
            }
        }]
    });

    new Ext.form.Panel({
        renderTo: document.body,
        width: 300,
        items: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Field 1',
            itemId: 'field1'
        },
        tbar: [{
            text: 'Mark',
            handler: function(){
                this.up('form').down('#field1').markInvalid('Foo');
            }
        }]
    });

});
```

Comment: +1 Good example. He is using ExtJs4 so you can use `Ext.create` instead.

Comment: You could, but in this case why would you? Everything is already required.

Comment: Better error messages. Just a matter of preference I guess ;)

Answer (score 0):

While you are creating the form object pass id dynamically so that you will have different form ids.

You can try with component query as well.